# How to use PEM keys from EC2

Tags: ssh, amazon-web-services, ssh-keys

I understand the concept of "ssh keys" to login to a server without entering a password, however, I am not understanding how/what PEM key files are to log in to EC2 instances.

In the AWS console, I can generate or import a PEM key, but where/how do I use this file on my  laptop to login to cloud instances?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Or you can create an entry on your .ssh/config as follows:

```
host myserver
hostname ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com
user username
IdentityFile path/to/your.pem
```

So after that you can ssh to your server like this: `ssh myserver`

According to PEM files, it's also good keep a copy in a safe place as it **can not be regenerated**.

Answer (score 3):

The other answers here are great, assuming that the destination server already has the `.pem` file's public key. In my case, I created a `.pem` file to access an existing server, which was not configured for my newly generate key. So here is how I managed to set up my server for access using my newly created `.pem` key:

**Create the public key from the `.pem` file:** `ssh-keygen -y -f my-new-key.pem > my-new-key.pub`

**Transfer the key to my server:** `scp -i ~/.ssh/my-old-key.pem /path/to/my-new-key.pub user@123.456.789:~/.ssh/`

**SSH into the server and attached the pem file as follows:** `ssh -i ~/.ssh/my-old.key.pem user@123.456.789` and run `cat ~/.ssh/my-new-key.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`

**Now, you can ssh into your server using your newly generated `.pem` key!** ie `ssh -i ~/.ssh/my-new-key.pem user@123.456.789`.

Answer (score 1):

from command line, just like this:

```
$ ssh username@exampleservername.com -i yourpemfile.pem
```

Then you can login to the server.